# Uncaught Reference Error: faceapi is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, face

I am currently having some issues with faceapi in javascript, faceapi is a code for your face to get detected, please help me with this error.

Code:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
  ]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        { video: {} },
        stream => video.srcObject = stream,
        err => console.error(err)
    )
}

startVideo()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `faceapi` in your code:

```js
var faceapi = "url or path to library"
```